# Navigating Consecutive Integer Quadratic Roots:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, quadratics

Prove that if $a$,$b$ and $c$ are consecutive positive integers then the roots of the quadratic equation of the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has Complex roots

My attempt:

In my attempt to grapple with this intriguing problem, I embarked on a journey through the realms of quadratic equations and consecutive integers. At first glance, the task seemed daunting, but I was determined to unravel its mysteries.

The discriminant of a quadratic equation determines the nature of its roots: positive for two real roots, zero for repeated roots, and negative for complex roots. So in this question I had to explore the scenario where the roots are complex.

First, I considered the relationship between the coefficients $a$, $b$, and $c$. Since they are consecutive positive integers, we can express them as (a), (a + 1), and (a + 2), respectively. Substituting these values into the discriminant formula, I obtained:

$D = (a + 1)^2 - 4a(a + 2)$

Expanding and simplifying this expression, I arrived at:
$D = a^2 + 2a + 1 - 4a^2 - 8a$
$D = -3a^2 - 6a + 1$

Despite my efforts, I found myself faced with a formidable challenge. The expression $D = -3a^2 - 6a + 1$ appeared enigmatic, defying easy interpretation. However, I refused to be deterred. I embarked on a meticulous analysis, exploring various avenues in search of insights but I failed.

Comment: Doesn't $a$ need to be at least $1$ by your hypothesis? So $D$ is at most...

Comment: For $a\ge 1$ , $-3a^2-6a=-3a(a+2)$ is obviously negative and the absolute value is clearly larger than $1$. Therefore , for $a\ge 1$ , we have $D<0$ meaning that there are no real roots.

Comment: What avenues did you explore?  Can you show $-3a^2-6a+1<0$ when $a\ge1$?

Comment: You were almost "home" and only missed the easy last step :)

Comment: I would have called the coefficients $(n-1,n, n+1)$ if increasing,  $(n+1,n, n-1)$ if decreasing, with discriminant $n^2 - 4 (n^2 - 1) = 4-3 n^2$

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there!

when $a,b,c$ are consecutive possitive integers the trinomial can be written

$nx^2+(n+1)x+(n+2)=0 $ ,

The discriminant in this case would be $D=(n+1)^2-4n(n+2)=-3n^2-6n+1 $

We know that $n$ is a possitive integer so $-3n^2,-6n+1 < 0 \implies D<0 $
We can also say that when $n\ge 1 , D \le -8<0$

So indeed the trinomial has $2$ complex roots

**If you are still not convinced**

We can let $n+1=y$ or $n+2=y$ and the discriminant is still negative